# Mapping of Function is Borel Measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Here's the problem:

Let X = (X1, X2, X3) be a vector of measurable real valued functions defined
on a measurable space (Ω, F). Define function Y (ω, t) : Ω × R :→ R by setting
Y (ω, t) = X1(ω)t$^2$ + X2(ω)t + X3(ω). Show that the mapping Y is F ⊗ B(R)/B(R) measurable.

I know that each function itself is measurable on (Ω, F) since each member of the vector is measurable, so X1, X2, and X3 each map from Ω to F. I'm just not sure how to show that it's measurable on F ⊗ B(R)/B(R), where F ⊗ B(R) is the product algebra. Very confused, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that your function is the composition of $X\times \operatorname{id}$ with the function $\Bbb{R}^4\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $(a,b,c,t)\mapsto at^2+bt+c$. This second function is a polynomial, hence continuous, and hence Borel measurable. Thus the composite is appropriately measurable. That said, your notation is slightly unfamiliar to me, so let me know if I'm misunderstanding what you're asking.

Comment: What does id stand for here? And sorry about the notation, this is what is used in the class and can be pretty confusing.

Comment: $\operatorname{id}$ is the identity map, in this case $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: The second part of the question is: Show that A = {ω : Y (ω, t) = 0 has two real roots } ∈ F and B = {ω ∈ A : the two roots are equal} ∈ F.
How would you use the answer to show the two roots are equal? Is that the t-value?

Comment: Try taking the discriminant of the polynomial, and show that that function from $\Omega$ to $\Bbb{R}$ is measurable in a similar manner.